# git - ''path'' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to clone a git repository from my desktop to my laptop.
The desktop is set up as ssh server and accessible from the laptop.

I tried several commands with different url formats,

```
git clone desktop:workspace/project
git clone desktop:/C:/Users/nkgcp/workspace/project
git clone desktop:~workspace/project
git clone ssh://desktop/workspace/project
git clone ssh://desktop/C:/Users/nkgcp/workspace/project
git clone ssh://desktop/c/Users/nkgcp/workspace/project
```

but these all returned the same error.

```
Cloning into 'project'...
fatal: ''workspace/project'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note that path on the second line is surrounded with two single quotes.

`project` exists inside `workspace` folder and it is definately initialized with git.
`workspace` folder is inside home directory of my desktop.

The desktop and the laptop is both Windows 10, and desktop uses built-in OpenSSH Server.
This is `sshd_config` of my desktop,

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no

AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory c:/Users/nkgcp

Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe
```

and this is `.ssh/config` of my laptop.

```
Host desktop
    HostName [desktop ip]
    User nkgcp
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

I checked debug logs of git ssh.

```
Cloning into 'project'...
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\nkgcp/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to desktop [192.168.25.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to desktop ([192.168.25.2]:22).
...
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'workspace/project'
...
debug1: Exit status 128
```

You can see only `git-upload-pack` was executed, so the error might come from this.

Answer (score 2):

First, check that `ssh desktop` works and open an interactive session.

Then, check that `ssh desktop ls /c/Users/nkgcp/workspace/project` does list the content of your remote repository.

I would also remove, for testing, the `ChrootDirectory` directive, just to check if it has a limiting side-effect.

Finally, try the clone command with:

```
git clone ssh://desktop/c/Users/nkgcp/workspace/project
```

See if you have any [`GIT_SSH` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_miscellaneous), and if not, see if setting it to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` or `C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` makes any difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, these doesn't seems to solve my problem.  
SSH connection has no problem. I can connect and use it without any problem.  
The error message might come from `git-upload-pack`.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out why.

`cmd.exe` seem to only accept double quote(") as string literal.
So when executing `git-upload-pack.exe 'workspace/project'`, not `workspace/project` but `'workspace/project'` is passed as an argument, which results in repository not found error.

To avoid this, you can simply [change default ssh shell of your server to powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows).
Or you can use `git clone host:repository -u 'powershell git-upload-pack.exe'` on the client side.